# issue with form C# asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm developping a website in asp.net 4.0 C#. I use mvc 4.0 
I have to realise a form but when I submit it . I would like to execute a certain method but I don't know how.

views:
    `<FORM action="...?..." method="post">
    <div class="identification">
    id 
    @Html.TextBox("id")
    password 
    @Html.Password("password")
    </div>
    <input  type="submit" value="login" />
    </FORM>`

controller (named loginControllers.cs)

```
public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
protected Boolean Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string p = "LDAP://wrexham.ac.uk";
    // string p = "LDAP://wxmdc1.wrexham.local";
    string u = id.text;
    string pw = password.Text;

    if (AuthenticateUser(p, u, pw))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(u, false);
        //FormsAuthentication.Authenticate()
        //FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUser.Text, chkPersistLogin.Checked)
        //FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(u, false);

        //FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()
        Response.Write("True");
        return true;


    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("false");
        return false;
    }
}

protected bool AuthenticateUser(string path, string user, string pass)
{
    //Simple Active Directory Authentication Using LDAP and ASP.NET
    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(path, user, pass, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
    try
    {
        //run a search using those credentials.
        //If it returns anything, then you're authenticated
        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
        ds.FindOne();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //otherwise, it will crash out so return false
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

}

Comment: The code you provided is definitely not for an MVC Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `LoginViewModel` that is required to handle user login detail and for the MVC view creation. For example:

**** Untested code!! ****

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember on this computer")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if user with given password exists in LDAP
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_username">User name</param>
    /// <param name="_password">User password</param>
    /// <returns>True if user exist and password is correct</returns>
    public bool IsValid(string _username, string _password)
    {

        //Simple Active Directory Authentication Using LDAP and ASP.NET
        var _path = "LDAP://a.b.c/dc=a,dc=b,dc=c";
        DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(_path, _username, _password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
        try
        {
           //run a search using those credentials.
           //If it returns anything, then you're authenticated
           DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
           SearchResult result = ds.FindOne();
           if (null == result)
           {
              return false;
           }               
           return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           //otherwise, it will crash out so return false
           return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And logic for your LoginController:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Login/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (model.IsValid(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login data is incorrect!");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Your login view:

```
@model Models.LoginViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login failed. Check your login details.");
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Login</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

Your _Layout.cshtml code should look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: auto; background-color: #728ea7;">
        @if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
            <strong>@Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name)</strong>
            @Html.ActionLink("Sign Out", "Logout", "Login")
        }
        else {
            @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Login")
            <span> | </span>
            @Html.ActionLink("Sign In", "Login", "Login")
        }
    </div>

    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create your view like :

```
@model Yournamespace.Models.ModelName


<div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("MethodName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "css class if any" }))
        {             
            <section>
                <div class="input-block">
                    <strong><label>yOur Label</label></strong>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Attribute)
                    <div class="UserIdValidation">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Attribute)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <p style="margin-top: 25px" class="input-block">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </p>              
            </section> 
        }
</div>
```

and your controller action should be like this :

```
 public class ControllerNameController : Controller
 {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(ModelName model)
        {           

              return View("VewName");
        }
 }
```